# Simple parallel line segment problem, driving me nuts!

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Given two parallel line segments: $z = a + bt,\ y = c + ds, \ t,s \in [0, 1]$  how do you compute the blue midpoints in the below picture, and if they don't exist (the segments don't "overlap" orthogonally), then take the closest two points between the segments as the answer.

This is a $\det = 0$ case for the closest two points among two line segments, and I've been stuck for hours writing the complex conditional statements in python, which are NOT WORKING!  Yes, I am fatigued.  But still, this should be easy.

What is the elegant formula for computing it?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the line joining the two blue dots has the same midpoint as the line segment joining $a$ to $c+d$ and the line segment joining $c$ and $a+b$. You can construct a right triangle from these.

Comment: @Kajelad True for the latter, but not necessarily so for the former. The illustration is drawn so that the lengths of $b$ and $d$ look equal, but that’s not a condition of the problem. All we know is that they’re parallel. For that matter, $b$ and $d$ could be antiparallel, in which case the latter line segment might not even intersect the segment joining the blue dots.

Answer (score 0):

First project $c$ onto the line of $y$: $c'= a + \big( b\cdot (c-a)/(b\cdot b)\big )b$.

Now $z' = c' + dt$ is $y$ orthogonally projected onto the line of $y$ and they're colinear now.

Now $z(s) = y(t)$ is possible, so $c'-a = bt - ds$. The vectors overlap if and only if $t, s = 0$ gives a solution solution in $s, t \in [0,1]$.

First find which line does that.  Now use a bunch of if conditionals to test outcomes of $s, t$ when subbing in $0, 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the dot products of the four end points with either of the direction vectors. It doesn’t matter which one as long as you use the same one for all four. Sort the mapped points in increasing order, find the average (midpoint) $m$ of the two inner values and map it back to values of $s$ and $t$. I.e., if we have $a'=a\cdot b$, $b'=(a+b)\cdot b$, $c'=c\cdot b$ and $d'=(c+d)\cdot b$, then the $t$-value of $m$ would be $(m-a')/(b'-a')$ and its $s$-value $(m-c')/(d'-c')$. If the $s$- and $t$- values are out of range, there was no overlap.